# Gravity grille not opening when bathroom fan is on

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I have a question about airflow with a bathroom fan, in this case a Ventaxia VASF100T with a front cover, duct through the wall and a gravity grille on the outside.

It seems quite inefficient at clearing steam, and I am wondering if the exterior vents are just stopping air from moving outside? What I am referring to is called a "gravity grille" I would have expected the flaps to open when the fan is on but I have checked and they do not move at all.
How can air be pulled outside if there is something blocking it? Maybe the air is just recirculating..

Comment: Have you looked at the fan blades in the last five years? They're probably so caked with lint that they're essentially drinking straw-shaped.

Comment: Also, it is common for people to underestimate the effect that bends in ducting have on airflow...

Comment: Sometimes the pivots on the flap get sticky, did you try to open the flap and see if it moves ?

Comment: This is a brand new installation.
One of the flaps was jammed and has been unstuck now.
They actually do open when the fan is on, but only a couple of mm
The fan has its own backdraft spring-loaded shutter, so hopefully that is opening fully also.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviving this thread after a long pause, as sometimes solving problems and discovering new ones happens over a long timescale with property!

The problem never truly got solved. The gravity flaps were opening a tiny bit, so I assumed that would be sufficient.

However, recently the exterior vent came away from the wall. It had been attached with rubber screw pads [image: rubber 'screws']

In checking this I discovered the bodger-bathroom installers had not installed any plastic ducting. This means air flow would be decreased without a clean flat channel, and damp air would be absorbed into the brick.

I am now installing some 100mm plastic duct <strike>with sleeves</strike> (both fan and vent have a sleeve that fits snugly over 100mm pipe) at either end to connect the fan and the vent, which should be airtight enough. I don't really want to start messing about with expanding foam as it's messy and above head height, so will just leave the ducting with a small gap around it, checking that water runs down and outwards (I placed a small pebble on top of the ducting at the outside to direct it downwards). The duct comes as 0.35m, which is exactly the right length to fit most UK brick walls that don't have a cavity. With the fan and vent pressed in place it didn't even need to be trimmed)

[image]

<strike>I will also try to drill 15mm holes in the brick once the ducting is connected up to properly secure the vent in place</strike> (edit: the vent was held in place well enough by attaching to the plastic duct - it slid on snug on both ends). This will mean if I choose to replace the duct or add foam I won't have to prise glue off the brick or hold it in place while glue sets. Finally, re-caulk (could have been neater if I'd screwed the vent tight, but it was an awkward spot to drill without the right ladder).

The ducting has cost me under a tenner, so to omit something like this seems unbelievably lazy and cynical.

And finally, the flaps open much more (with the door closed) now that the air has a direct frictionless path to travel

[image: flaps are adequately opening]

Comment: That's what they look like in normal operation, +1. If it doesn't, then it prob also 'looks like that' *on the inside* and is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

The outside grille should definitely open when the fan is running. However, it isn't clear whether this is a cause or an effect of your airflow problem:

- The grille may be stuck, in which case you need to lubricate/free/unbind it
- There may be some other issue with the airflow, in which case nothing's pushing the grille open

First stop: check the grill manually so that you can see if they're working (they should open easily). If not, you've found the problem. If so, then you'll need to check other components (the ducting, the fan, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, previously the flaps were hardly opening at all.
The bottom had some silicone sealant on it. That was a separate issue.
However, the reason why the flaps were hardly opening, even after the stuck flap was rectified, was that there was no ducting - this significantly reduced the airflow to the outside (due to friction / turbulence).
Once I installed plastic ducting myself yesterday, the flaps now open correctly as seen in the recent photo, as the commenter above said; 'normal operation'. Ducted air needs a smooth uniform and ideally straight channel to pass through efficiently.

I answered my own question with another account - apologies if that caused confusion. I was updating the thread so that anyone looking for a solution to a similar problem would first confirm that ducting was correctly installed, as the lack of ducting turned out to be significantly reducing airflow to the outside.

The fan now resonates a little at the frequency of the pipe, but that's much preferable to a fan performing weakly and allowing moist air to circulate in the bathroom and into the (solid, no cavity) brick wall.

I discovered the lack of ducting when the vent came loose.
So, I'm both highlighting how and why a fan should be properly installed, and drawing attention to yet another unprofessional bodger-builder.

Maybe they had very poor common sense, were too lazy to google how to do one of the basic jobs in installing a bathroom, or thought, 'no one will ever see that it's just a bare hole in the brick, or if they do, we will be long gone'.

Comment: Please ask a moderator to merge your accounts.

Comment: I've done that. This thread should make more sense now!